# matplotlib: drawing a horizontal line spanning over multiple subplots, with interactive mode

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using interactive mode in matplotlib to calculate some parameters. I want to plot two subplots horizontally, then draw a horizontal line that goes through both of them. I reproduced my problem as in the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np
plt.ion()
f,axarr=plt.subplots(1,2,sharey=True,gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[100,1]})
axarr[0].set_title('subplot_1')
axarr[1].set_title('subplot_2')
axarr[0].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axarr[1].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
for i in range(100):
    data_1 =np.random.randint(100,size=1)
    data_2=np.random.randint(100,size=1)
    axarr[0].bar(i,data_1,width=1)
    axarr[1].bar(1,data_2,width=1)
    axarr[0].axhline(y=data_2+5,xmin=0,xmax=i,c='yellow',linewidth=10,zorder=0,clip_on=False,animated=True)
    axarr[1].axhline(y=N_level+20,c='yellow',xmin=0,xmax=1,linewidth=10,zorder=0,clip_on=False,animated=True)
    plt.pause(0.000000000001)
```

But this code doesn't generate this horizontal line. I need to have a plot similar to this figure 
[image]

Comment: maybe you want something like : https://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/multicursor.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `animated=True`. This will show the line.

Now the problem is that you add a new line for each iteration step, such that at the end, the complete plot will be yellow. To avoid that, I would suggest to define the line outside the loop and only update its position for each step.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np
plt.ion()
f,axarr=plt.subplots(1,2,sharey=True,gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[50,1]})
axarr[0].set_title('subplot_1')
axarr[1].set_title('subplot_2')
axarr[0].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axarr[1].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

line = axarr[0].axhline(y=0,xmin=0,xmax=1,c='yellow',linewidth=2,zorder=5,clip_on=False)

for i in range(100):
    data_1 =np.random.randint(100,size=1)
    data_2=np.random.randint(100,size=1)
    axarr[0].bar(i,data_1,width=1)
    axarr[1].bar(1,data_2,width=1)
    line.set_ydata([data_1,data_1])
    plt.pause(0.000000000001)
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Note that I left out the second line, because the variable is undefined in the code and I don't know what it should be showing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.